# Accessing a method from a callback in OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm new to OOP and this might be a simple question but I am having trouble accessing a method in this class:

```
class Lightbox {
  constructor() {
    this.images = document.querySelectorAll("figure > a");
    this.lightbox = document.querySelector("#lightbox");
    this.lightBoxImage = this.lightbox.querySelector("img");
    this.events();
  }

  showLightbox() {
    this.lightbox.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  populateLink(source) {
    this.lightBoxImage.src = "";
    this.lightBoxImage.src = source;
  }

  events() {
    this.images.forEach(function (image) {
      image.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

        console.log(this); // Returns the "Image", which this refers to the "image", can't access the prototype above

        e.preventDefault();
        this.showLightbox(); //Not a Function, can't access.
        this.populateLink(this.href);
      });
    });
  }
}

let lb = new Lightbox();
```

How can I access the `showLightbox()` method when `this` refers to the `image`? I've tried using `.bind(this)` on my callback but I still can't access `showLightbox()`.

Comment: Use arrow function instead of normal function inside forEach loop ?

Comment: I tried that, I can get `this.href` to populate correctly, but I can't figure out how to run the `populateLink(this.href)` function as its scoped to the forEach loop or the Event Listener. If I try it the other way around, I can't grab the `this.href` as it has a global scope. Make sense?

Comment: Arrow functions all the way down, and `this` is always your class instance.

Comment: Ahhh.. Nice. I like that approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by declaring the following:

```
  events() {
    const self = this; // Grabbed the global scope as a variable
    this.images.forEach(function (image) {
      image.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.populateLink(this.href); //able to access global method.
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: While this works and this was the *only* way to do this prior to ES6, modern JavaScript can easily do this better and more clearly with arrow functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions